# what is difference between '... v=7.0' and http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

Hi i tried to load animatedTileLayer in my bing maps application but i got some errors in javascript  if i used to v=7.0 but working perfectly using the  second Url.

So please explain me what is difference between

http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0
and http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol

Comment: It's two different URL's, not only appending `?v=7.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The v=7.0 URL is the URL tot eh Bing Maps V7 API which was released about 6 or 7 years ago. The second URL is for the Bing Maps V8 API which was released last June. V8 has twice as many features as V7, and supports rendering a lot more data than V7 as well. The AnimatedTileLayer class is new in Bing Maps V8. The URL to Bing Maps V8 doesn't include a version number as one of the goals is to only update this version incrementally going forward rather than releasing a whole new version in the future. You should definitely be doing all development against Bing Maps V8. Bing Maps V7 will reach the end of its life at the end of June.